# Why my code is printing an heart at printf?

Tags: c, string, build, logic

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main(){
    char *alf="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%&.",text[64];
    int i, alfl=69;
    srand(time(0));
    for(i=0;i<64;i++)
        text[i] = *(alf+rand()%alfl);
    printf("%s",text);
}
```

But at the printf function it print an heart at final of the string.

Comment: You need to zero-terminate the string you put into `text`. Strings in C must be zero terminated if you want to do things with them like print them.

Comment: Answer to any "C string" question: Null terminator misunderstanding.

Comment: Is it only me or "and heart at printf" doesn't really make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have suggested in the comments (@mbratch and @KerrekSB) you need a null terminator at the end of your string.

Modify your code as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main(){
    char *alf="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%&.",text[64];
    int i, alfl=69;
    srand(time(0));
    for(i=0;i<63;i++)
        text[i] = *(alf+rand()%alfl);
    text[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s",text);
}
```

And it should work, but as @Simon suggested there can be other things that could help improve your code and understanding of C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 64

int main() { // If you don't add a return type, int is assumed. Please specify it as void or int.
    const char *alf="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%&."; // This string cant be assigned to. Make sure that you stay "const-correct".
    char text[LEN]; // Please avoid magic numbers here too by using a constant
    int i, alfl = strlen(alf); // As @Simon says, it is better to not use magic constants.
    srand(time(0));
    for(i=0;i<LEN-1;i++)
        text[i] = *(alf+rand()%alfl);
    text[i] = '\0'; // make sure to null terminate your string.
    printf("%s",text);

    return 0; // If your return type is int, you must return from the function.
}
```

Comment: +1: I'd also suggest writing `alfl = strlen(alf);` (which would require `#include <string.h>`) to avoid errors due to miscounting the number of characters in `alf`, which humans are prone to do and computers are not prone to do ...

Comment: @Simon, You're right, so I went back and changed a couple more things. It was a quick and dirty initial answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Several suggestions:

1. `main` should `return` an `int`:

   ```
   int main(void)
   {
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. You should use `strlen` to determine the length of strings:

   ```
   alfl = strlen(alf);
   ```
3. It's easier to use array notation:

   ```
   for(i = 0; i < 64; i++)
       text[i] = alf[rand() % alfl];
   ```
4. If you use `text` like a string, it must be `'\0'` terminated:

   ```
   text[63] = '\0';
   ```

Comment: @nonsensickle I knew you were on the prowl.  I had to act fast.